# .NET Table Adapter Select query is slow when using variable only in application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, tableadapter

I am using the .NET TableAdapter to execute a SELECT query in my application, as shown below. The problem is this type of queries sometimes takes several minutes to execute. However, while I tested it in the SQL server, it returns the result in a flash. (Doing `SET ARITHABORT ON/OFF` and `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` could fix the problem sometimes, but not always.)

```sql
/*The query defined in the designer.cs*/
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3...
FROM MyTable
WHERE column1 = @var1 AND column2 = @var2
```

If I remove the variables to use literals, it fixes the speed.

```sql
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3...
FROM MyTable
WHERE column1 = 'Billing' AND column2 = 'New'
```

Using `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` does not work as well. I think it still sends the parameters as separate variables, for SQL Server to process.

Finally, I tried to use variable in SQL Server, but it does not slow down any speed. Hence, I wonder if using variable is actually the problem. (shouldn't `TableAdapter` replace the variables with literals before sending the query?)

```sql
DECLARE @status va1= 'Billing'
DECLARE @status var2= 'New'

SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3...
FROM MyTable
WHERE column1 = @var1 AND column2 = @var2
```

Is there way to get the performance fixed, without changing all queries with variables to literals?

Comment: There may be parameter sniffing.  Consider encapsulating your queries in stored procedures. SQL Server often handles stored procedures differently, and parameter sniffing may behave differently as well.

Comment: In addition: I've looked at the Execution plans in the new query tab in visual studio. They look identical to the plans in SQL server, but I'm not sure if it applies to the queries using the TableAdapters.

Comment: Encapsulating the query into stored procedures did not work in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use variables like @var1 and @var2 in your query, SQL Server must generate a query execution plan that considers the potential values of these variables. SQL Server tries to create a plan that is suitable for various parameter values. This process can lead to a suboptimal execution plan in some cases, especially if the distribution of data in your table is uneven.

On the other hand, when you use literals like 'Billing' and 'New' in your query, SQL Server can generate a query execution plan that is specific to these constant values. This can result in a more efficient execution plan because it doesn't have to consider different possible values.

My suggestions;

Ensure that the statistics for the columns involved in your query are up to date. Outdated statistics can lead to suboptimal query plans. You can use the UPDATE STATISTICS command to update statistics for specific tables and columns.

```
UPDATE STATISTICS MyTable
```

Also you can clear the cache for a specific query using DBCC FREEPROCCACHE, but use this carefully as it can affect overall server performance.cached query plans can become less efficient.

Comment: Updating STATISTICS does speed up the query from running over a minute to 20 seconds!

Comment: However, it is still incomparable to the speed of using literals. Should I consider to look into how to replace parameters to literals using variable or query string concatenating? (which I know sounds insecure)

Comment: Maybe you can try with different query hints like OPTIMIZE FOR or OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN

Comment: it's not a recommended long-term solution due to security risks.

Comment: The performance is fixed after updating the statistics and use OPTION(RECOMPILE).

Comment: Although, I do wonder if rebuilding the query plan every time is a harm in long-term?

Comment: Recompiling queries for every execution can introduce some overhead in high-traffic systems.

Comment: if you have encounter a problem, consider using other techniques like indexing, query optimization, and statistics maintenance to minimize the need for frequent plan recompilations.